# Delimiter collides with letter using scalerel

Tags: unicode-math, scalerel

In order to be able to use brackets from custom fonts, I am using `scalerel` package. Everything works great except the letter f is really curved and collides with delimiters. To make the issue more apparent, I used a bold font square bracket. You can see in the picture, the f is colliding with the square bracket and it even crosses it occasionally.

Fonts are available here: https://github.com/proafxin/antique_book
Sorry for the extra step but this is probably the best example to show the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{CenturymodernTT-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{CenturymodernTT-Italic.otf}[range={it}]
\setmathfont{IMFELLDoublePicaRomanSC.otf}[range={"007B-"007D,"0028-"0029,"002F,"005B-"005D,"00A7,\mid,},FakeBold=0]

\usepackage{scalerel,iftex}
\newcommand{\squarebracket}[1]{\ifxetex{\scaleleftright[1ex]{[}{#1}{]}}\else{\left[#1\right]}\fi}
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\ifxetex{\squarebracket{#1}}\else{\left\lfloor{#1}\right\rfloor}\fi}

\begin{document}
        \begin{align*}
            \sum_{n\leq x}F(n)
                & = \sum_{d\leq x}\floor{\frac{x}{d}}f(d)
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is LaTeX problem...? You need to ask the font designer to specify italic correction etc. properly...?

Comment: I agree, it's a font issue, but nothing that a little additional kerning couldn't fix. Try something like this: … \sum_{d\leq x}\floor{\frac{x}{d}}\kern 2pt f\kern 1.25pt(d)

Comment: I thought so too except when using \left[\right] there is no collision with the same letter

Comment: @Ingmar it worked thank you